# Python Ghostscript Repair pdf

Tags: python, pdf, ghostscript

I have pdf Files where I recieved the message from PyPDF2 "incorrect startxref pointer(1)".
Now I want to repair the pdf Files with Ghostscript and Python.

I installed:

pip install ghostscript
ghostscript 10.01.1

But now I´m lost. Even with the Examples of Python-ghostscript I don´t now how to start.
I found the syntax

```
  -o repaired.pdf ^
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
  -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress ^
   corrupted.pdf
```

Can someone help me?

```
import sys
from ghostscript import _gsprint as gs

args = [
    b"gs",  # actual value doesn't matter
    b"-o repaired.pdf",
    b"-sDEVICE=pdfwrite",
    b"-dPDFSETTINGS=/press",
    b"corrupted.pdf"
    ]

instance = gs.new_instance()
code = gs.init_with_args(instance, args)
code1 = gs.exit(instance)
if code == 0 or code == gs.e_Quit:
    code = code1
gs.delete_instance(instance)
if not (code == 0 or code == gs.e_Quit):
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use package PyMuPDF (owned by same company as Ghostscript) all the way throughout your app? PyMuPDF opens PDFs and automatically repairs any requiring it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have GhostScript installed and on your path, you don't need a Python wrapper for it.

Maybe something like

```
import shutil
import subprocess


def repair_pdf(in_file, out_file):
    gs = shutil.which("gs")
    if not gs:
        raise RuntimeError("Ghostscript not found")
    subprocess.check_call(
        [
            gs,
            "-dSAFER",
            "-dNOPAUSE",
            "-dBATCH",
            "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite",
            "-o",
            out_file,
            in_file,
        ]
    )


repair_pdf("corrupted.pdf", "repaired.pdf")
```

Comment: Can I suggest an edit ? "-dPDFSETTINGS=/press" should be "-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress". There is no such option as /press for PDFSETTINGS. I'd also suggest dropping it entirely, the defaults do the best job of preserving the input.

Comment: @KenS Absolutely, good catch.